# Matplotlib - plot Date relative to Time - Python 3.3

Tags: python, date, python-3.x, matplotlib

Evening all,

I'm trying to use Matplotlib to plot a graph of dates relative to time.  The time is in hours, minutes, seconds; the date is in day, month, year.

```
times = ['10:11:30','02:04:09','07:55:10']
dates = ['01/11/2013','02/11/2013','03/11/2013']
```

Ideally I would like the chart to show dates along the bottom in `dd/mm/yyyy` format, and time along the y axis as `HH:MM`.

Now, I have spent many hours reading and coding to try to produce this chart but have been unable to do so.  I won't bore you with the details of my failed attempts but I would really appreciate if someone could show me how to do this.

Kelly.

Comment: Also, just a note on the question I pointed to as a duplicate: Currently, matplotlib uses a float-based array for datetimes, where a difference of 1.0 corresponds to 1 day.  Now that numpy has built-in datetime array support, there are other common conventions for (non-object) arrays of datetimes.  That answer assumes that you're using the internal matplotlib representation. If need to use a different representation, that should point you in the right direction. (Or you can just convert.)